# How to read from Lua arrays into c# using NLua?

Tags: c#, arrays, lua, nlua

I have seen a few other posts, but they are the opposite of what I want to do.
I simply have an array of ints in my lua file, and I want to know how I change that into a c# array. Using *lua ["ints[1]"]* throws an exception.

I think this would be very useful to know for many people, as it could be used for tilemaps, or many things really.

Comment: Could You please provide full code example and the exception itself?

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/NTmpW7Bn) I am just trying to read id's from a file into a 2D array in the same order, using  a lua file. But, using the lua ["codeid"] with lua arrays causes an NullReferenceError.

Answer (score 0):

The array of integers you have on the Lua side is just a Lua table and on the C# side it's a `LuaTable` type.

Do this:

```
lua.DoString(@"
    my_array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
");

LuaTable myArray = (LuaTable) lua["my_array"];

foreach(var val in myArray.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

Result:

[image]